# getting ngrx running with angular 8

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

recently discovered the redux pattern and I'm trying to follow the steps defined in the ngrx.io site for installation and setup. However, I'm running into issues. given how 'fresh' angular 8 is, is this supposed to work?

- Install Angular 8
- Mak sure sure Angular CLi is also version 8
- create a new app "ng new ngrxfire"
- once complete, cd into the directory and "run ng add @ngrx/store"

the following error is shown in the console

```
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.
```

I do see that the package.json has been updated with ngrx, as seen below

```
    "@ngrx/store": "^1.2.1",
```

however, when I go to import the 'storeModule' via

```
import { StoreModule} from '@ngrx/store';
```

the StoreModule can't be found

it should be noted that this all works if I use angular 7.2 rather than 8.

I see that ngrx has a 'next' version that isn't official yet. Should I not be using Angular 8?

Comment: version `1.2.1` is very old like 3 years old... latest is `7.4.0` or `8.0.0-rc.0` using @next.

Comment: thank you. installing it with "npm isntall @ngrx/store/@latest" rather than using "ng add" seems to have gotten things working. not sure why ng add pulled an old version.